# Unix bash shell scripting permissions

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, permissions

I am supposed to use r, w, h, k keys in the script. h for moving the cursor to the left, k for moving the cursor to the above line. r for changing the permissions of the group, user or others depending on the cursor position. and same with w key.
I was able to do the h and k keys, but for r key, i am having problem getting the current position and applying chmod for r and w keys. Below is my code:

```
stty -icanon min 1 time 0 -echo
command=$(dd bs=3 count=1 2> /dev/null)
case $command in

  q) rm /tmp/temp.$$
     stty icanon echo
     tput cup $myLine 0
     exit 0 ;;

  h) if [ $index != 0 ] 
     then
       tput cub 999
       currPos=$(( index - 1 ))
       tput cuf ${positions[$currPos]}
       index=$(( index - 1 ))
     fi ;;

  l) if [ $index != 9 ]
     then
       tput cub 999
       currPos=$(( index + 1 ))
       tput cuf ${positions[$currPos]}
       index=$(( index + 1 ))
     fi ;;

 r) if [ $index != 0 ]
     then
       tput cub 999
       currPos=$((index -1 ))
     fi ;;

  k) if [ $currentLine != 1 ]
     then
       tput cud 1
       tput cub 99
       tput el
       echo ""
       tput cuu 3
       tput cuf 26
       if [ $onFile = false ]
       then
         cd ..
       fi
       links=$(ls -ld . | awk '{print $2}')
       owner=$(ls -ld . | awk '{print $3}')
       group=$(ls -ld . | awk '{print $4}')
       size=$(ls -ld . | awk '{print $5}')
       date=$(ls -ld . | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}')
       tput cub 99

       echo "  Links: $links  Owner: $owner  Group: $group  Size: $size  Modified: $date"
       tput cuu 2
       tput cub 999
       tput cuf ${positions[$index]}

       onFile=false
       currentLine=$(( currentLine - 1 ))
     fi ;;
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: *" i am having problem"* - please describe the problem.  BTW, all those `ls` and `awk` processes could be replaced by `read perms links owner group size d1 d2 d3 junk < <(ls -ld .)` then `date="$d1 $d2 $d3"`.  Alternatively, check to see if you have the `stat` program.